# How to get SessionId

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm trying to create an userEntity based on Dialogflow's [reference](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/userentities#post_userentities%20reference) but I could'nt find how to get the SessionId that is expected as parameter, can someone that had done this before cast some light on the subject for me? All answers related to Dialogflow that I've managed to find were regarding to V1 and looks like it changed a lot on V2.

Answer (score 0):

The userEntity has been replaced with a [session entity](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions.entityTypes) under V2. As you note, you need to use the sessionID as part of the name of this Entity.

Since you'll be doing this as part of the fulfillment, you can get this as part of the parameters that Dialogflow sends your webhook as part of the top-level attribute `session` in the JSON sent to you. If you're using the dialogflow-fulfillment library, this should be under `agent.session`.